# How do I use a newly created variable in the same select statement?

Tags: sql

How do I reuse a variable (column) which I just created in the same `select`?

```
create table t2
as select count(bar) as foo, foo * log(foo) as ifoo
from t1
group by bar;
```

as you can see, I am creating `t2.foo` (the number of times each value of `bar` appears in `t1`) and I want to use that value to compute `t2.ifoo`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible approach is this:

```
create table t2
as
    select foo, foo * log(foo) as ifoo
    from (
        select count(*) as foo, bar
        from t1
    ) q
    group by bar;
```

I don't know what `bar` is here, but it doesn't matter, you just need to make sure it exists in the subquery.

Comment: @sds, I believe the answer to that is once; but you'd have to look at the execution plan.

Answer (score 1):

You need to repeat the same function in the second column

```
create table t2 as 
  select count(*) as foo, 
         count(*) * log(count(*)) as ifoo
  from t1
  group by bar;
```

(Note - perhaps you meant to create a view here, or maybe just a query, but this isn't valid syntax for creating a table. The same logic will apply though - you can't use the alias of the column in the same statement to refer to itself, the logic must be repeated).

Comment: @sds the query optimizer should ensure that count(*) is only calculated once for each row being returned.